# What is the right association for a child model that can be attached to different types of parent model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'm using Rails, although this applies to any OO/SQL system, really.

I have a Note model and a Comment model. Notes can have many Comments. This is straightforwards, but now I want to add a new model, LearningObjective, which can also have many Comments. What is the right way to do this? The only thing I can think of is to have a column in the Comments table, which has the name of the parent model in it and a parent_model_id column. Otherwise I have to have two separate columns in the Comments table, one for note_id and one for learning_objective_id, with messy checks for which one is null.

Is there a typical pattern used for a situation like this? Maybe an intermediate model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you describe is most often addressed with polymorphism, which is basically exactly what you theorise in your question. Polymorphism is [easy](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) in Rails; an example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class LearningObjective < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

You'll have two columns in your `comments` table to handle this relationship: `commentable_type` and `commentable_id`, which will store the class name and the id respectively of the association.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an intersection table for this:

```
    +---------------------+
    | Comments            |
    +---------------------+
    | commentID | comment |
    +---------------------+

    +---------------+
    | Notes         |
    +---------------+
    | noteID | note |
    +---------------+

    +-------------------------+
    | LearningObjective       |
    +-------------------------+
    | objectiveID | objective |
    +-------------------------+
```

Now for your intersections:

```
    +------------------------------------+
    | NoteComment                        |
    +------------------------------------+
    | noteCommentID | commentID | noteID |
    +------------------------------------+

    +------------------------------------------------------+
    | LearningObjectiveComment                             |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
    | learningObjectiveCommentID | commentID | objectiveID |
    +------------------------------------------------------+
```

That is how I would do it, sure there are other solutions as well